# How to Add a Third Level Sub Menu to the Wordpress Admin Menu

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, admin, wp-admin, admin-menu

Is there a function, action or filter that I can use to add a third level drop-down menu to the WordPress admin menu.

For instance, right now in the sidebar menu, there is a menu for posts and under posts there are sub-menus for editing posts, adding a new post, categories, and tags.  There is something similar for Pages.

What I would like to do is to add a menu item called Content and place underneath content Posts, Pages and my Custom Content Types and underneath each of those entries the relevant sub-menus (editing, adding, etc.).

I would like to do this through a custom plugin that I create.  The problem is, I can't find any information on how to add a third-level sub-menu.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: IMO you can not!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, it is not possible to create third level menu in admin panel. If you look at the definition of **add_submenu_page**, you need to mention the parent slug name. **For eg:**

```
add_menu_page ( 'Test Menu', 'Test Menu', 'read', 'testmainmenu', '', '' );
add_submenu_page ( 'testmainmenu', 'Test Menu', 'Child1', 'read', 'child1', '');
```

The first parameter of the **add_submenu_page** will be parent slug name. So you may think we can write **child1** as *parent slug name* to create the third level. **Eg:**

```
add_submenu_page ( 'child1', 'Test Menu', 'Child2', 'read', 'child2', '');
```

But this will not work. Look at the parameters definition and source section in this [link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_submenu_page/). It clearly states that, you can only use the name of '**main menu of the plugin**' or the **file name** of the WordPress plugin in **parent slug name**. So it is not possible to create submenus more than once in admin panel. However, you can create *n* number of sub menus in front end. To know more about creating menus and sub menus in front end, [refer](https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/how-to-create-custom-menu-structures-in-wordpress)

Comment: There is no work-around or hack?

Comment: You could always javascript something, there is always a way to hack something.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote it myself using JS. It's just for one project and I didn't want to spend much time on it, so you have to adjust it for your personal needs ;)

It hides chosen menu elements and creates a button which toggles them.

You add it to the end of file
/wp-admin/menu-header.php

```
<script>
    // Here is list of classes of chosen menu elements you want to toggle - li.menu-icon-slug
    let my_products = document.querySelectorAll("li.menu-icon-okna, li.menu-icon-drzwi, li.menu-icon-bramy_garazowe");
    
    my_products.forEach(prod => {
        prod.style.backgroundColor = "#283338";
    })
    
    // "Produkty" is a text on a toggling button, change it
        let my_button = jQuery('<li class="menu-top"><a class="menu-top"><div class="wp-menu-image dashicons-before dashicons-admin-post"></div><div class="wp-menu-name">Produkty</div></a></li>')[0];

        document.querySelector("ul#adminmenu").insertBefore(my_button, my_products[0]);

    function toggleProducts() {
        my_products.forEach(prod => {
            if(prod.style.display != "none") prod.style.display = "none";
            else prod.style.display = "block";
        })
    }
    toggleProducts();

    my_button.querySelector("a").addEventListener("click", toggleProducts);

</script>
```

.
.
with no jQuery:

```
<script>
    // Here is list of classes of chosen menu elements you want to toggle - li.menu-icon-slug
    let my_products = document.querySelectorAll("li.menu-icon-okna, li.menu-icon-drzwi, li.menu-icon-bramy_garazowe");

    my_products.forEach(prod => {
        prod.style.backgroundColor = "#283338";
    })

        let prod_li = document.createElement("li");
        prod_li.classList.add("menu-top");

        let prod_a = document.createElement("a");
        prod_a.classList.add("menu-top");

        let prod_div1 = document.createElement("div");
        prod_div1.classList.add("wp-menu-image","dashicons-before","dashicons-admin-post")

        let prod_div2 = document.createElement("div");
        prod_div2.classList.add("wp-menu-name");

        // Text on a button:
        prod_div2.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Produkty"));

        prod_a.append(prod_div1, prod_div2);
        prod_li.append(prod_a);

        document.querySelector("ul#adminmenu").insertBefore(prod_li, my_products[0]);

    function toggleProducts() {
        my_products.forEach(prod => {
            if(prod.style.display != "none") prod.style.display = "none";
            else prod.style.display = "block";
        })
    }
    toggleProducts();

    prod_a.addEventListener("click", toggleProducts);

</script>
```